# How to inherit template abstract class with a class with template secification

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a project on linux that builds into static library, which then I want to include in unit test project and in app project.

In this library I have something like that:

```
template<class T> class A
{
public: 
    virtual T doStuff() = 0;
    virtual void doOther(T a) = 0;
protected:
    A() { ... }
};

class B : public A<int>
{
public:
    B() { ... }
    virtual int doStuff() { ... }
    virtual void doOther(int a) { ... }

};
```

I am getting compilation error: `undefined reference to A<int>::A()` in my lib. 
I'm guessing it has something to do with template generation, and also can I override virtual functions like that?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b80ad3f08319f32). Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes, you can override virtual functions like that. The compiler would let you know if not.

Comment: @Angew - I had my class members definitions in cpp files, not in header files like in this example here. I thought that's completely irrelevant, totally forget about basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

templates are generated during compile time and needs to be implemented in the same translation unit they are prototyped. So, if you are including a declaration of a templated class, you also need to include the definition.

So, it would be prudent to have both the declaration and definition in the same header file, so that, any module that intends to use it, when compiled can generate the definition as required.

Refer:

**14.7.2 Explicit instantiation [temp.explicit]**

> For a given set of template arguments, if an explicit instantiation of
>   a template appears after a declaration of an explicit specialization
>   for that template, the explicit instantiation has no effect.
>   **Otherwise, for an explicit instantiation definition the definition of
>   a function template, a member function template, or a member function
>   or static data member of a class template shall be present in every
>   translation unit in which it is explicitly instantiated.**

Comment: Could you explain the relevance of the quote you included, please? There are no explicit instantiations in the question's code.

Comment: Even if you made that part bold, that doesn't change the fact that the quote refers to a language construct that simply doesn't appear in the question code (`A<int>` is *not* an explicit instantiation), so it's not clear at all what you want to say. In case the OP's problem is caused by not including definitions when using templates, explicit instantiation could be a solution, but you need to explain it as such.

Comment: I totally forget about that part - was refactoring a lot and thought I did include my .cpp in .h files (using `#ifndef MY_CPP` `#define MY_CPP` ... `#endif`)
When I did that now, it fixes my issue. 
Long time since programming using templates, and those errors could be more specific ;p